# Is the Arizal quoted in the Shittah Mekubetzes?

Tags: arizal

Someone told me that the Arizal is quoted in the Shittah Mekubetzes. Is this true?
If true, please provide a source.

Comment: The Arizal was a student of the Shita Mekubetzes

Comment: @Chatzkel as I understand it, he was a Talmid-Chaver, in which case it wouldn't be so crazy that he'd be mentioned in the Shittah.

Comment: @AaronReese that was my point. It can be that it’s mentioned, I don’t know for sure though. They definitely knew each other